# My characters in my 2D game do not collide even when i create 2D collider box

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to make the characters in my game collide with objects around them and stop moving. the thing is the characters just spawn and keep walking down the map until they're out of the Canvas view.

[image: image of the characters moving.]

my characters have Constantmove script that i assigned to them which is this one:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterConstantMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    GameManager Game_Manager;

    void Start()
    {

        GameObject gameController = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameController");
        Game_Manager = gameController.GetComponent<GameManager>();

    }


    void Update()
    {

        transform.Translate(Game_Manager.moveVector * Game_Manager.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        
    }
}
```

**What do i do to make them stop around the desk and just stay idle when they collide there?**

Comment: If you want physics in your game you have to add the`RigidBody2D` component to the objects that should actually respond to each other (in addition to the `BoxCollider2D`). Then set the gravity scale to 0 if they should not fall out of the screen.

Comment: To stop them moving, you'll probably have to have a flag that specifies them to stop moving when something happens.
So a variable called "isMoving" that is set to false when "OnCollisionEnter2D" happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving them with transform.Translate() function, which does not include physics. If you want them to collide, you would have to add Rigidbody2D component and move them using velocity property: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html

Comment: so do i delete the whole code of constant movement and start new one with rigidbody2D component? or do i add it to the same code i have?

Comment: I would delete and start new one